# Does an aircraft carrier have a VOR onboard?

Tags: aircraft-carrier, radio-navigation, us-navy

I wouldn't think so due to the impracticality of VOR on a moving platform, but aircraft still need to navigate to the aircraft carrier. Would the radial shift around as the boat rocked around? The enemy could use the VOR to literally home in on the carrier as well.

Comment: "Apollo to Galactica.  Is your autoland offline?" *The reimagined series (2004)*

Comment: The USN is not the only navy with aircraft carriers.

Answer (score 34):

Aircraft carriers use a TACAN, which stands for Tactical Aid to Navigation.  (The Navy is really good at making acronyms that don't follow normal conventions for abbreviation)

Functionally the TACAN is like a VOR with DME, providing bearing to and from the ship, as well as range.  The system is not susceptible to rocking motion, and least not perceptibly.  (and if you are already familiar with VORs, a VORTAC is a landbased co-located VOR and TACAN station.)

And true, an enemy could pick up the signal.  For this reason carrier airwings need to prove themselves proficient in EMCON (Emission Controlled) launch and recovery operations before being certified ready for deployment.  During an EMCON recovery crews are told where to expect the ship, what the expected recovery course will be, and  will be given a marshalling lat/long.

At the appointed time, and with no radio communication, formation flights will peel off the bottom of the holding stack, drop to break altitude,  head towards where the ship should be, and sequence themselves in with traffic in the pattern.  It is a pretty amazing thing when it works.

Comment: So an EMCON landing is like landing at an uncontrolled field except that there is zero radio communication. And the field is moving. And the weather may be horrible. And many if not most of the aircraft are low on fuel. And the pilots are all mentally exhausted. Good thing they're all well trained and know what to expect.

Comment: The Navy tends to avoid acronyms. They prefer abbreviations. You can find them in the [DICNAVAB](https://www.amazon.com/Dictionary-Naval-Abbreviations-Bill-Wedertz/dp/0870211552) - Dictionary of Naval Abbreviations.

Comment: TACAN deals with the ship motion by having the antenna mounted in a gimbal so that it remains mostly level.

Comment: _It is a pretty amazing thing **when it works**._ - It probably is a pretty amazing thing when it doesn't work.

Comment: @Aleks G, generally no, when EMCON is broken is it usually just a needed radio call breaking the silence, and a collective feeling of disappointment that it wasn't as clean as it might have been.

Comment: @AleksG Imagine a formation peeling off from a holding stack, heading towards where the ship should be, and there's no ship there so they precisely glide into the water and disappear never to be seen again. At least, it would be funny if they were autonomous planes.

Comment: You'd expect they'd be using laser beam communications right now. They're pretty narrow, making it virtually impossible to listen in if you're in the " wrong" spot.

Comment: @user253751 You'd have at least some visual sense on the pilots' part.  If the ship isn't there, they will not just glide into the water, I'd hope.

Comment: @AleksG Another reason why it would be much funnier with autonomous aircraft. Perfectly stable, but it doesn't know the ship isn't there. I knew we shouldn't have gotten the intern to write the landing algorithm!

Comment: @MSalters, I can't see how lasers would be practical.  Flight cycles are typically 1.5 hours, with roughly 20 aircraft airborne, perhaps operating above a heavy layer of clouds, plus the ship will be within a few miles of where it plans and moving all the time.  How might the airplanes be tracked and use lasers to find the ship?

Comment: @MichaelHall I assumed that the meaning was laser-based communications with the ship on final. Though, at that point, I'm not sure why communication would be especially necessary.

Comment: @Gerry That thing is 330 pages?! It's amazing Navy personnel can tell the abbreviations apart...

Comment: OMG, I thought that was a joke!

Comment: @Gerry: How does that compensate for the antenna's lateral motion (tending to shift the detected azimuth clockwise and anticlockwise in an oscillating pattern) as the ship rocks from side to side?

Comment: @Sean To my knowledge it doesn't, but it's not really necessary. TACAN is for finding the ship, not a precision approach. As an estimate, if the antenna is 30 m above the roll center and the ship is rolling +/- 20 deg, the antenna will be translating about 30 m left to right. At a distance of 1 NM (fore or aft) that woud cause about 1 deg bearing change. At longer distances it would be hardly noticeable. Besides, I'm not sure it's all that relevant these days. Between GPS and secure datalink there are other way to find the ship than a UHF beacon.

Comment: There is visual communication during the last phase of landing between the aircraft and the ship. The ship is lit (somewhat). Other ships should be keeping the bad guys away from the carrier anyway.

Comment: @Gerry Many things on Navy ships are synchronized with the orientation of the ship. Synchros send yaw, pitch and roll information to things all over the ship, including radar antennas. I would expect TACAN to be similar.

Comment: @MSalters I suspect that lasers would not work very well in rain or fog, especially given that you don't want to dazzle the pilots (visible wavelengths) or damage their retinas (visible and IR wavelengths) when the beam direction is changed by water droplets. While there might be plenty of space on the ship for a receiver which can feed back to the airborne transmitter which way to aim, there would not be that space on an aircraft. And you really don't want a retroreflector on a combat aircraft.

Comment: Just wait until he finds out about Air-to-Air TACAN